# How to encode datatype IRIs for RDF values in JSON-LD?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

A JSON-LD context can be used to specify the range of a property.  E.g., the following stats that the range of `rdf:value` consists of integers:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "rdf:value": { "@type": "xsd:integer" }
  },
  "rdf:value": "1"
}
```

​In RDF modeling it is common to use different ranges for different uses of `rdf:value`.  E.g., the following expresses that an object costs €2,50 and has temperature 28.2 ℃ (using Turtle notation):

```
_:1 ex:price [ rdf:value "2.50"​^^xsd:decimal ; ex:unit ex:euros ] ;
    ex:temperature [ rdf:value "28.2"^^xsd:float ; ex:unit ex:degreesCelsius ] .
```

How do I describe this in terms of a JSON-LD context?  It seems to me that I need property paths (borrowing a concept from SPARQL) as keys, specifically the following for the current example:

```
"ex:price/rdf:value": "xsd:decimal"
"ex:temperature/rdf:value": "xsd:float"
```

Is there a way to specify this in JSON-LD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also [nest `@context`](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#advanced-context-usage) to specialize/override properties. To take your example:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "rdf:value": { "@type": "xsd:integexr" }
  },
  "rdf:value": "1",
  "ex:price": {
    "@context": {
      "rdf:value": { "@type": "xsd:float"}
    },
    "rdf:value": "35.3"
  },
  "ex:temperature": {
    "@context": {
      "rdf:value": { "@type": "xsd:decimal"}
    },
    "rdf:value": "2.50"
  }
}
```

You can [experiment with this in the JSON-LD Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22rdf%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Aintegexr%22%7D%7D%2C%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ex%3Aprice%22%3A%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Afloat%22%7D%7D%2C%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%2235.3%22%7D%2C%22ex%3Atemperature%22%3A%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Adecimal%22%7D%7D%2C%22rdf%3Avalue%22%3A%222.50%22%7D%7D).

Another approach is to use custom properties that all map to one `@id` (`rdf:value`) but with different datatypes:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "value_integer": {
      "@id": "rdf:value",
      "@type": "xsd:integer"
    },
    "value_float": {
      "@id": "rdf:value",
      "@type": "xsd:float"
    },
    "value_decimal": {
      "@id": "rdf:value",
      "@type": "xsd:decimal"
    }
  },
  "value_integer": "1",
  "ex:price": {
    "value_decimal": "35.3"
  },
  "ex:temperature": {
    "value_float": "2.50"
  }
}
```

See [this example on the JSON-LD playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22rdf%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22value_integer%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22rdf%3Avalue%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Ainteger%22%7D%2C%22value_float%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22rdf%3Avalue%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Afloat%22%7D%2C%22value_decimal%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22rdf%3Avalue%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3Adecimal%22%7D%7D%2C%22value_integer%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ex%3Aprice%22%3A%7B%22value_decimal%22%3A%2235.3%22%7D%2C%22ex%3Atemperature%22%3A%7B%22value_float%22%3A%222.50%22%7D%7D).

Comment: This requires me to include the nested context for each such property.  Is there not a more general way to express this, i.e., stating once that `"p/q": {"@type": "xsd:float"}` rather than stating `"q": {"@type": "xsd:float"}` for each occurrence of `"q"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [typed value](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#typed-values) by specifying a [value object](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#value-objects).

Example:

```json
{
  "@context": 
  {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  },
  "rdf:value": 
  {
    "@value": "1",
    "@type": "xsd:integer"
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to express the datatype IRI in a context so I can specify it once and do not need to repeat it.

Comment: @WouterBeek: Ah. So what about defining different properties in the `@context`, each with the same `@id` but different `@type`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to introduce separate properties. Something like (I also set `@vocab` to `ex` here):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "price_value": { "@id": "rdf:value", "@type": "xsd:decimal" },
    "temperature_value": { "@id": "rdf:value", "@type": "xsd:float" },
    "@vocab": "http://ex.org/",
    "unit": { "@type": "@vocab" }
  },
  "price": {
    "price_value": "2.50",
    "unit": "euros"
  },
  "temperature": {
    "temperature_value": "28.2",
    "unit": "degreesCelsius"
  }
}
```